# Google analytics admin api : The caller does not have permission

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

**Edit : i just add email service account in my dashboard analytics user admin, and its working**

So I would like to use google API to create property with datastream. (using laravel)
And I have one issue regarding authentication :
[image]

"The caller does not have permission"

I don't understand because, I'm creating service account with "Owner" right, I also activated my API and service account is inside...

I don't see which roles/group I am missing.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to check the prerequisites, ensuring on your service account with IAM roles:

- `roles/admin.analytics.edit`
- `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` (if using BigQuery as the data source)
- For your Laravel application, install the `google/apiclient` package (`composer require google/apiclient)`
- For the API Credentials, download the JSON key file for your service account and store it securely in your Laravel project.